Was ist der Unterschied zwischen gegen, wider, entgegen und dagegen?
Sind sie nicht absolut austauschbar? Kann mir bitte jemand bei dieser Frage helfen?

Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher, die Du konsultiert hast, dazu?

Wider und gegen sind als präposition nahezu immer austauschbar. Allerdings gibt es Situationen, in denen das eine oder andere merkwürdig klingt.
Klingt gut - Klingt merkwürdig
Wir spielen gegen die anderen. - Wir spielen wider die anderen.
Das ist wider die Natur. - Das ist gegen die Natur.
Er lief gegen die Wand. - Er lief wider die Wand.
Es war wider meiner Erwartung. - Es war gegen meine Erwartung.
Entgegen kann als Präposition in vielen Fällen wie "gegen" verwendet werden.
Das war entgegen meiner Erwartung.
Sie handelte entgegen seinen Willen.
Entgegen des Vorschlages trank er weiter.
Aber als Adverb heißt es, dass sich zwei Dinge in zwei um ca. 180° gedrehte Richtungen bewegen. Oder alternativ, dass sich ein Ding auf ein anderes zubewegt.
Wir gehen der Sonne entgegen.
Auf der anderen Fahrspur kommen uns Autos entgegen.
Bei "dagegen" will ich die gleiche Empfehlung aussprechen wie Planetmaker und den Duden empfehlen. Dafür gibt es 6 mögliche Bedeutungen mit Beispielen:
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dagegen
Drei möchte ich aber hervorheben.
Dagegen ist praktisch um etwas in Argumentationen zu vergleichen.
Die Pflanze A hat eine kräftige grüne Farbe entwickelt. Dagegen hat Pflanze B einen faden gelben Ton angenommen.
Wenn etwas an etwas lehnt oder an etwas drückt.
Als er vor der Wand stand lehnte er die Leiter dagegen.
Sie müssen nur dagegen drücken, dann geht die Tür auf.
Als Angriff, Abwehr oder Ablehnung gegen diese Sache bzw. Angelegenheit.
Dagegen sind wir machtlos. (Abwehr)
Wir müssen uns dagegen auflehnen! (Angriff)
Ich habe etwas dagegen. (Ablehnung)
